# Counting non-zero entries in the matrix representing a relation R on a set A with Python code

Tags: python-3.x, math

I made the code to solve the problem below. Although it works, it looks not efficient. Does anyone have recommendations to make it more Pythonic?

*How many non-zero entries does the matrix representing a relation  on a set  consisting of first 100 positive integers have if  is {(, ) |  and  have common divisors except 1}?*

```
def commonDivisor(n):
    nums = list(range(2, n+1))
    sum = 0
    for idx, num in enumerate(nums):
        if num % 2 == 0 and num % 3 != 0  and num % 5 != 0:
            sum += 50
            print(idx,num,sum)

        elif num % 2 != 0 and num % 3 == 0  and num % 5 != 0:
            sum += 33
            print(idx,num,sum)

        elif num % 2 != 0 and num % 3 != 0  and num % 5 == 0:
            sum += 20
            print(idx,num,sum)

        elif num % 2 == 0 and num % 3 == 0  and num % 5 != 0:
            sum += (50 + 33 - (100//(2*3)))
            print(idx,num,sum)

        elif num % 2 == 0 and num % 3 != 0  and num % 5 == 0:
            sum += (50 + 20 - (100//(2*5)))
            print(idx,num,sum)

        elif num % 2 != 0 and num % 3 == 0  and num % 5 == 0:
            sum += (33 + 20 - (100//(3*5)))
            print(idx,num,sum)

        elif num % 2 == 0 and num % 3 == 0  and num % 5 == 0:
            sum += (50 + 33 + 20 - (100//(2*3*5)))
            print(idx,num,sum)

        else:
            sum += (100//num)
            print(idx,num,sum)

    return sum
```

Comment: Do you want code that will calculate the desired value for any number of positive integers, not just 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `100` is not large, and the number of entries in your relation matrix of size `100` is only `100**2 = 10000` which is also not large for a computer program. The function `math.gcd` finds if two numbers have a common divisor greater than `1`, and the time complexity to calculate `math.gcd(a, b)` is `O(log(min(a,b)))`. So checking the GCD for all pairs of numbers up to 100 this is complexity of only `46052` which again is not large.

So you can calculate your number the direct way with this pythonic code:

```
from math import gcd
n = 100
print(sum(1 for a in range(1, n+1) for b in range(1, n+1) if gcd(a,b) > 1))
```

This is simple, pythonic, and works for any value of `n` above zero.

Note that my code prints `3913` while yours returns `3756`. My code seems very straightforward and checks for small values of `n` so I suspect that your code is wrong. Your code is so specific to `n=100` that it is very difficult to check. But it seems that you ignore all prime divisors other than `2,3,5`. You leave out possibilities such as `(7, 49)`, `(11, 22)`, `(97, 97)`, and so on.

My code, however, is slow for large values of `n`. Below is much more complex code that calculates the same thing but is much faster for large `n`. For `n=100` my old code uses 2.7 milliseconds but my new code does it in 139 *microseconds*, about 1/20 the time. The discrepancy would be greater for larger `n`.

This code finds the combinations of prime numbers below 100. Two numbers have a common divisor greater than one if they are both divisible by at least one prime number (the same prime for both numbers). For example, there are `100 // 2` numbers from 1 to 100 that are divisible by 2, thus `(100 // 2) ** 2` pairs of numbers with a common factor that is itself divisible by 2. There are `(100 // 3) ** 2` pairs of numbers with a common factor that is itself divisible by 3, and so on. These counts overlap, so we must remove the repeated counts using the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). We *subtract* the number divisible by *both* 2 and 3 get rid of that overlap. The multiplier `1 if len(c[0]) % 2 else -1` in my code handles the addition/subtraction decision.

I also use a list of primes in my new code. In my opinion, anyone doing work with divisibility should have a long list of primes available to greatly speed up the calculations. My own list has the first 6542 prime numbers, all those that fit into a 2-byte unsigned integer.

```
primeslist = [
      2,     3,     5,     7,    11,    13,    17,    19,    23,    29,
     31,    37,    41,    43,    47,    53,    59,    61,    67,    71,
     73,    79,    83,    89,    97,   101,   103,   107,   109,   113,
]

def prime_combinations(n):
    """Generate combinations of distinct primes where their product is
    less than n. Each yielded item is a 3-tuple containing:
    - the combination in increasing order,
    - the product of the primes in the combination,
    - k where the last and largest prime in the combination is the k'th
      prime (where 2 is the 1st prime.)
    Items are yielded in lexicographical order. The first item yielded
    is the empty combination ((), 1, 0).
    """
    def primecombos(prefix, prod, ndx):
        yield prefix, prod, ndx
        while True:
            newprime = primeslist[ndx]
            newprod = prod * newprime
            if newprod >= n:
                return
            yield from primecombos(prefix + (newprime,), newprod, ndx+1)
            ndx += 1

    if 1 < n <= primeslist[-1] and n == int(n):
        yield from primecombos((), 1, 0)    

def commonDivisor2(n):
    """Count the number of pairs of positive integers less than or 
    equal to n that have a common factor greater than 1.
    """
    pcombs = prime_combinations(n+1)
    next(pcombs)  # throw away the empty combination of primes
    return sum((1 if len(c[0]) % 2 else -1) * (n // c[1]) ** 2
               for c in  pcombs)  # c[0] is combination, c[1] its product
```